# Strange temporary array corruption

Tags: c++, arrays, corrupt

I am attempting to create a permutation, and I receive this strange error when I finish my problem:

```
Stack around the variable "temp" was corrupted
```

the segment of the variable is within a nested for loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < str_length ; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < str_length ; j++)
    {
        char temp[1];

        temp[1] = text[i];
        text[i] = text[j];
        text[j] = temp[1];

        cout << text << endl;
    }
}
```

text is initialized outside of the for loop as a string, and I get the same error when i make temp[1] into a char or an int. The program works fine but I am concern why I am receive this error, does anyone know why?

Comment: If you want unique permutations consider using `for(int j = i + 1;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to use `char temp;` and acces it as `temp = text[i];`, etc.

You're accessing a point on the stack one byte PAST temp, which is invalid.  In this case, since you only want a single char, there's no need for an array at all.

Answer (score 10):

temp[1] does not exist, you should be doing temp[0]. Or alternatively, like this:

```
char temp;
temp = text[i];
text[i] = text[j];
text[j] = temp;
```

or

```
char temp[1];
temp[0] = text[i];
text[i] = text[j];
text[j] = temp[0];
```

Answer (score 7):

use `temp[0]` to access the first element